# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

The error says this:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used (SQL: select `Marcas`.`nombre` as `Marca`, `Modelo`.`nombre` as `Modelo`, `Vehiculos`.`year` as `Anio`, `Vehiculos`.`id` from `Vehiculos` inner join `Reservaciones` on `Vehiculos`.`id` = `Reservaciones`.`id_vehiculo` inner join `Marcas` on `Vehiculos`.`id_marca` = `Marcas`.`id` inner join `Modelo` on `Vehiculos`.`id_modelo` = `Modelo`.`id` where `Vehiculos`.`id_marca` = 1 and `Marcas`.`id_categoria` = 2 and `Vehiculos`.`id` not in (select *))
```

And this is my query in laravel:

```
public function checkDisponibilityByDate(Request $req){
    $fecha = $req->fecha;

    $vehiculos= Vehiculo::join('Reservaciones', 'Vehiculos.id', '=', 'Reservaciones.id_vehiculo')
    ->join('Marcas', 'Vehiculos.id_marca', '=' , 'Marcas.id')
    ->join('Modelo', 'Vehiculos.id_modelo', '=' , 'Modelo.id')
    ->select('Marcas.nombre as Marca', 'Modelo.nombre as Modelo', 'Vehiculos.year as Anio', 'Vehiculos.id')
    ->where('Vehiculos.id_marca', '=' ,$req->id_marca)
->where('Marcas.id_categoria', '=' ,$req->id_categoria)
->whereNotIn('Vehiculos.id', function($fecha) {
        Reservacion::select('Reservaciones.id_vehiculo')
        ->from('Reservaciones')
          ->where('Reservaciones.fecha', '=', $fecha);
})
->get();
return $vehiculos->toJson();
}
```

I hope you can help me with this, I'm working with Laravel 5

Comment: See at the very end of the query where it says `...and Vehiculos.id not in (select *)`. See the problem there?

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be because you are not returning anything from your `whereNotIn` callback. But I'm not proficient at eloquent so maybe it does some magic.

Comment: Try changing that to `return Reservaction::select`

Comment: It doesn't work @Barmar

Comment: Try with `whereNotIn('Vehiculos.id', function($query) use($fecha){ $query->select('id_vehiculo')->from('Reservaciones')->where('Reservaciones.fecha', '=', $fecha);`. Which Laravel version are you using L5.0 or later? You are mixing eloquent with query builder which doesn't seem to be the best practice. Without the table structure and model relationships code it is not possible to provide with alternative approach.

Comment: Hey @Barmar , I would like to request you to reopen the question as, I think,  it is not mysql specific problem, the problem is rather with the structuring of eloquent/query builder query. Reopening the question will enable more pointers in answers to the OP.

Comment: @Donkarnash The question I linked to is about Laravel query builder, and shows the correct way to strucure a `WHERE IN (SELECT ...)` query. But I'll reopen if you think you can do a better job of providing a helpful answer.

Comment: @Barmar I have not been able to put it properly. My point is that the question you linked to - OP has just requested a query builder syntax for a simple `whereNotIn()` which does relate to the current OP's question, but here the OP has a conditional `whereNotIn()` with additional parameter where the OP is not passing the parameter correctly to the `whereNotIn()` and also he is mixing eloquent and query builder calls which I think is not good. So reopening this question may lead to more explanation in form of answers - is what I think.

Comment: @Donkarnash I don't use Laravel, but my understanding is that you can put a query of any complexity in the `whereNotIn()`, so the additional parameter should not make a difference. But I've reopened it. Maybe if the OP can solve his problem using that answer he can post his updated code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to pass a parameter to the query you need to pass it with `use($fecha)`

```
public function checkDisponibilityByDate(Request $req)
{
    $fecha = $req->fecha;

    $vehiculos= Vehiculo::join('Reservaciones', 'Vehiculos.id', '=', 'Reservaciones.id_vehiculo')
                ->join('Marcas', 'Vehiculos.id_marca', '=' , 'Marcas.id')
                ->join('Modelo', 'Vehiculos.id_modelo', '=' , 'Modelo.id')
                ->select('Marcas.nombre as Marca', 'Modelo.nombre as Modelo', 'Vehiculos.year as Anio', 'Vehiculos.id')
                ->where('Vehiculos.id_marca', '=' ,$req->id_marca)
                ->where('Marcas.id_categoria', '=' ,$req->id_categoria)
                ->whereNotIn('Vehiculos.id', function($query) use ($fecha) {
                    $query->select('id_vehiculo')
                          ->from('Reservaciones')
                          ->where('fecha', '=', $fecha);
            })
            ->get();
    return $vehiculos->toJson();
}
```

Or you can simplify the `whereNotIn` by constructing the array separately

```
public function checkDisponibilityByDate(Request $req)
{
    $fecha = $req->fecha;
    $check = Reservacion::where('fecha', $fecha)->lists('id_vehiculo');

    $vehiculos= Vehiculo::join('Reservaciones', 'Vehiculos.id', '=', 'Reservaciones.id_vehiculo')
                ->join('Marcas', 'Vehiculos.id_marca', '=' , 'Marcas.id')
                ->join('Modelo', 'Vehiculos.id_modelo', '=' , 'Modelo.id')
                ->select('Marcas.nombre as Marca', 'Modelo.nombre as Modelo', 'Vehiculos.year as Anio', 'Vehiculos.id')
                ->where('Vehiculos.id_marca', '=' ,$req->id_marca)
                ->where('Marcas.id_categoria', '=' ,$req->id_categoria)
                ->whereNotIn('Vehiculos.id', $check)
            })
            ->get();
    return $vehiculos->toJson();
}
```

Hope this helps.

If you can share your models and table structure then probably other/pure eloquent like approach can be suggested.